# How do I put the whole path in cd command in GitBash

Tags: git-bash

Whenever I want to open a repository I need to use the cd command multiple times in order to open it. Does the command only works that way or there is an efficient method which I am missing out on?
For context :
Everytime I need to :
cd C:\users
cd Win10
cd Desktop
cd Dump
cd Rep1

How do I open this repository in a single go?

Comment: Have you tried just putting them after each other with backslashes in between? The backslash is something called a path sepperator (which are different between windows (backslash) and unix-likes (forward-slash) ). It goes between the folders of a path. A path is the path your computer goes to look for a file or directory

Comment: `cd C:\users\Win10\Desktop\Dump\Rep1` ?

Comment: bash: cd C:\users\Win10\Desktop\Dump\Rep1: No such file or directory.
It shows this error if I do it that way. PS : the path is correct since it works when I do it individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bash session, you would need `/`, not  `\`:

```
cd C:/users/Win10/Desktop/Dump/Rep1
# or
cd /c/users/Win10/Desktop/Dump/Rep1
```

That would switch to the right folder.